# Insert creating multiple register from one table to another

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
Eployee ID     Start Month       End Month
1              3/4/2013          26/11/2017
2              20/12/2014
3              1/8/2017          30/01/2018
```

I need to create a new table that will contain one register for each month an employee has worked up to date (if there is no end month it's still working)

I need to get something like this

```
Month       Employee ID
4/2013          1
5/2013          1
...
11/2017         1
12/2014         2
1/2015          2
...
current month   2
8/2017          3
...
1/2018          3
```

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What do you mean with "register"?

Answer (score 0):

If, you are working with `SQL Server`, then *recursive* `cte` is one option :

```
with t as (
     select EmployeeID, StartMonth, EndMonth
     from table
     where EndMonth is not null
     union all
     select EmployeeID, dateadd(mm, 1, StartMonth), EndMonth
     from t
     where StartMonth < EndMonth
)

select EmployeeID, concat(datepart(mm, StartMonth), '/', datepart(year, StartMonth)) as Month
from t
union all
select EmployeeID, concat(datepart(mm, getdate()), '/', datepart(year, getdate()))
from table
where EndMonth is null
order by EmployeeID;
```